# Issues with Orbot and Orfox

Tags: orbot

Cannot get Orbot or Orfox to work on my Galaxy S6. Android version 6.0.1. I start it and closes it down then restart it. Still no luck.

Comment: What does the log show? You can swipe it in from the right when you're on the main screen.